# Find out number of users with a particular OSX version for Mac App Store app

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I know there are a lot of tools out there for collecting iOS app statistics, but would like to specifically find out statistics for a mac desktop app distributed via the App Store. It would be nice to see the OS version breakdown (in aggregate, of course – no need to know individual cases) in order to know when/if it's a good time to drop support for a particular OS version.